# Are Weretigers Large when in Hybrid or animal form?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, creature-size, lycanthropy

A person from my group found out an inconsistency regarding the Weretiger template in the 5E Monster Manual page 207. It describes the animal and the hybrid form to grow to enormous size (the same is stated above for the werebear) but later on on the table of the werebear we see that it describes their shapechange like this:

> The werebear can use its action to polymorph into a Large bear-humanoid hybrid or into a Large bear, or back into its true form, which is humanoid. Its statistics, other than its size and AC, are the same in each form.

Whereas the Weretiger table gets this:

> The weretiger can use its action to polymorph into a tiger-humanoid hybrid or into a tiger, or back into its true form, which is humanoid. Its statistics, other than its size, are the same in each form.

In the table of the Weretiger we see no mention of growing to enormous size (large) and also in the table it mentions that all statistics remain the same except its size... but wait there is no mention to the size changing... How can it be?

So here is my question.
Is it possible that the developers forgot to add the word Large tiger-humanoid hybrid and Large tiger ?

If it turns out to be true what me and my group found, then we found something that should get into the next errata.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you flip to page 339 of the Monster Manual, you can see that tigers are Large creatures. There are several different varieties of bear, some of which are Medium, some of which are Large. So the Werebear had to specify that its bear form is a Large creature, but the Weretiger's tiger form will logically be Large.

Note that the Wererat's Shapechanger trait also mentions that its size changes, and doesn't include a size keyword, which is because the Wererat transforms into a giant rat, a small creature. So that's nice and consistent.

The remaining (less consistent) question is whether the Weretiger's *hybrid* form is Large. Given that the description of the Weretiger says that it grows to enormous size in its hybrid and animal forms, (the same wording as the Werebear, which none of the other lycanthropes have), it seems reasonable that the Weretiger's hybrid form is also Large.

It certainly seems possible (even likely) that the writers forgot to add the Large keyword to the Weretiger's Shapechanger trait, but ultimately, it's up to you to decide whether you want the Weretiger's hybrid form to be Large or Medium.

Answer (score 4):

Perusing the Monster Manual, it might seem that only Werebears change their size when they shapechange. I will list the entries here:

> **Werebear**: The werebear can use its action to polymorph into a *Large* bear-humanoid hybrid or into a *Large* bear, or back into its true form, which is humanoid. Its statistics, other than its size and AC, are the same in each form.
>
> **Wereboar**: The wereboar can use its action to polymorph into a boar-humanoid hybrid or into a boar, or back into its true form, which is humanoid. Its statistics, other than its AC, are the same in each form.
>
> **Wererat**: The wererat can use its action to polymorph into a rat-humanoid hybrid or into a giant rat, or back into its true form, which is humanoid. Its statistics, other than its size, are the same in each form.
>
> **Weretiger**: The weretiger can use its action to polymorph into a tiger-humanoid hybrid form or into a tiger, or back into its true form, which is humanoid. Its statistics, other than its size, are the same in each form.
>
> **Werewolf**: The werewolf can use its action to polymorph into a wolf-humanoid hybrid or into a wolf, or back into its true form, which is humanoid. Its statistics, other than its AC, are the same in each form.

It might seem that only the Werebear even gets a size increase, and that sounds about right since Bears are *huge*, much larger than Boars, Rats, Tigers, or Wolves.

However, looking at the statistics blocks for a Tiger, it is a *Large* Beast. And in the Weretiger's shapechange text, as with the Werebear and Wererat, says this:

> Its statistics, other than its size [and AC for the Werebear], are the same in each form.

Looking up the Giant Rat, the Giant Rat is Small. And only those three Lycanthropes have size change in their shapechange abilities. The Werebear can become Large, the Weretiger can become Large, and the Wererat can become small.

Comment: It would make sense to me too if it only did not say later on that all its statistics remain the same except its size.

Answer (score 0):

The way I interpreted this was as follows:

All Lycantheropes in humanoid or hybrid form are Medium sized unless explicitly stated otherwise such as in the case for the Werebear.

All Lycanthropes in Animal Form are the size of that animal.
The text for Werewolves and Wereboars does not include them changing size because thier animal forms are the same size as thier other forms.

Wererats turn into Giant Rats which are Small, Werewolves turn into wolves which are Medium, Wereboars turn into boars which are Medium, Weretigers turn into Tigers which are Large, and Werebears turn into Large Bears.

Werebears are a bit strange in a few ways. When it says Large bear, it is unclear if it is intended to mean a bear that is already Large (which just excludes the Black Bear), or you become a bear and its size is large(in this case, if it were a Black Bear, you would just be a Large Black Bear rather than a Medium Sized one).  It doesn't matter much, since it just come down to hair/fur color and if you went with the first interpretation and discluded the Black Bear, I would just use the Cave Bear for individuals with dark colored hair.

Note: Cave bear is a Variant of the Polar Bear found underneath its entry in the Monster Manual. They share the same stats with the only difference being that cave bears have dark fur and darkvision.

So to answer your question specifically, I would rule that Weretigers are Medium in hybrid form, despite the text saying they "grow to enormous size in animal and hybrid form". That phrasing is vague as 'enormous' is a relative term, it doesn't nessesarilly mean they both transformations grow the creature to the next size category or even by the same amount. The only Lycantherope that I would say has a large Hybrid form is the Werebear, though both the Werebear and the Weretiger are Large in animal form.

It wouldn't be unreasonable to make a Weretiger Large in hybrid form, based on what is presented in the Monster Manual, but that is up to your interpretation.